# Node.js locking to one user at a time

Tags: node.js, locking

I am building a really simple web application with Node.js. The purpose of this application is to allow a user to edit settings of some running computations from a browser. I would like to restrict the application to allow only one user at a time, so to avoid any conflicts. If another user connects to the application while some user is already there, the second one should be notified, that the application is in use by another user.

What is a preffered way to achieve this with Node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you build a simple session object ("model") that manages the connected users and only allows one connected session at a time. Perhaps sessions could timeout after 90 seconds of inactivity.

[Here's a quick sessions tutorial](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions) which shows you how to use a raw session (`req.session`), a redis backend, or a mongodb backend. A basic [express middleware](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#middleware) could be used to manage the sessions and set a limit of 1.

If you want something more advanced, maybe look into [Passport](http://passportjs.org/).